# Android OrmLite emptyString for String defaultValue

Tags: android, ormlite

I am using OrmLite 4.46 to manage my database for my android application.

And i have one problem:

I have the following code for my model:

```
public class Item extends Model {

        @DatabaseField(generatedId = true)
        private long        id;
        @DatabaseField(columnName = "item_name", defaultValue = "")
        private String      name;
        @DatabaseField(columnName = "item_count", defaultValue = "0")
        private int         count;

        public Item() {
            super();
        }
}
```

And the problem is here :

```
@DatabaseField(columnName = "item_name", defaultValue = "")
private String      name;
```

When i am creating a new Item() with no arguments and i save it in the database, normally in the column item_name it should save an empty String.

But when i am retrieving the item from the database and i try

String itemName = item.getName().trim() I get a NullPointerException

So it seems that the name is null.

Also i checked the created table from the above model in the sqlite db file and when i set `defaultValue=""` the column is created with no default value.

Does anybody know of any solution to this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can initialize name field to empty string at class level like:

```
@DatabaseField(columnName = "item_name", defaultValue = "")
private String name = "";
```

This will initialize name field to empty string when you create object of class `Item` and save it to database.

When you retrieve it from database the name field will be empty (`""`) instead of `null`.

Comment: Thank you, it fixes my problem in the more simple way because the workaround i have found was to make defaultValue=" " and then trim the string to see if it is empty.

Answer (score 1):

> When i am creating a new Item() with no arguments and i save it in the database, normally in the column item_name it should save an empty String.

Although @Rakesh's answer is correct, this turns out to be a bug in [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/).  The code is supposed to insert the `defaultValue` during a create if the field is `null`.  However, there was an errant `.equals("")` that was stopping this.

I've submitted the [following bug report](https://sourceforge.net/p/ormlite/bugs/152/) and have fixed it in trunk.  It will be in 4.47.

Comment: Thanks, i ll use Rakesh solution for the time being. Waiting for 4.47!! :) Thanks for your time.